# How to bridge a VLAN and a physical interface with netplan?

Tags: vlan, netplan

I have two workstations running Ubuntu 22.04 Server using netplan for network device management.

The first workstation has 5 NICs. The only two that I think matter for this are `enp0s25` and `ens1. Here is my netplan config from that workstation:

```
network:
  renderer: networkd
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp0s25:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      link-local: []
      ignore-carrier: true
    enp10s0f0:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      link-local: []
      ignore-carrier: true
    enp10s0f1:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      link-local: []
      ignore-carrier: true
    ens1:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      link-local: []
      ignore-carrier: true
  vlans:
    vlan10:
      accept-ra: no
      id: 10
      link: enp0s25
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: true
      link-local: []
      interfaces:
        - enp0s25
    br1:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      link-local: []
      addresses: [10.233.20.90/23]
      interfaces:
        - vlan10
        - ens1
      parameters:
        forward-delay: 0
        stp: true
    br2:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      link-local: []
      interfaces: [enp10s0f0]
    br3:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      link-local: []
      interfaces: [enp10s0f1]
```

I have created `vlan10` attached to the physical interface `enp0s25` which is a VLAN with ID 10. I have attached both `ens1` and `vlan10` to `br1`. I have a whole bunch of devices plugged into the physical network connected to by `ens1`. I have a bunch of VMs attached to `br1` using libvirt. The physical devices and VMs communicate just fine.

**My theory was that untagged layer 2 traffic coming in ens1 would wind up tagged with vlan 10 on enp0s25**. However I might have this all wrong.

I tried to confirm this using `tcpdump` running on the host

```
$ sudo tcpdump -i enp0s25 -n 'vlan 10'
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on enp0s25, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
23:45:01.873478 90:9a:4a:31:6d:58 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, RRCP-0x25 query
23:45:02.416923 ARP, Request who-has 10.233.20.199 tell 10.233.20.205, length 46
23:45:02.871227 90:9a:4a:31:6d:58 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, RRCP-0x25 query
23:45:03.417030 ARP, Request who-has 10.233.20.199 tell 10.233.20.205, length 46
23:45:03.745380 ARP, Request who-has 10.233.21.24 tell 10.233.20.90, length 28
23:45:03.872080 90:9a:4a:31:6d:58 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, RRCP-0x25 query
```

It seems like this works?

My second workstation (similar hardware) has a netplan like this

```
network:
  renderer: networkd
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp0s25:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      link-local: []
      ignore-carrier: true

  vlans:
    vlan10:
      accept-ra: no
      id: 10
      link: enp0s25
    vlan100:
      accept-ra: no
      id: 100
      link: enp0s25

  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: false
      link-local: []
      interfaces:
        - enp0s25
    br10:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: false
      link-local: []
      interfaces:
        - vlan10
    br100:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      link-local: []
      interfaces:
        - vlan100
```

My assumption was that I could see the vlan 10 traffic on the second workstation. Running   `sudo tcpdump -n -i enp0s25 'vlan 10'` does not show what I would expect

```
$ sudo tcpdump -n -i enp0s25 'vlan 10'
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on enp0s25, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
23:50:54.153304 IP 0.0.0.0.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 92:e7:5b:f0:b0:7a, length 292
```

The DHCP traffic is just the local machine trying to get an IP since I asked netplan to run DHCP on the brdige. I'm not seeing the VLAN tagged frames show up on this machine at all.

Is there an issue with my setup here? Is there something more I need to do in order to get this to work?

**Update:** I plugged my laptop's ethernet port directly into the 1st workstation. I see the same traffic using `tcpdump` on vlan 10 that I see running it on the host. So is it possibly my network switches somehow do not pass 802.1Q traffic? All my switches are 'dumb switches' which I would assume do not care about the 802.1Q field.